# SSRS - Sending Excel attachment & Body in html

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, rendering, subscription

I have 2 data sets:

- Email as in excel attachment -- Detail
- Summary as HTML in Body of the email -- Summary count of the 1st result set

How can we do this in SSRS? Currently I am using the 2 result sets in one excel and in 1 Email. But I want send the email as Summary Dataset 2 redult in Body of the Email and result set 1 as Excel attachment.

Comment: Please clarify. I have no idea what I'm reading.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to write some code for this I think as I don't think the SSRS scheduler is flexible enough to do what you want. I don't use the scheduler, I wrote a program that works fairly much how you describe here.

First up, you want to create a HTML email:

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage("me@mycompany.com", "you@mycompany.com");
message.Subject = "Here is your report!";
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

Now, for the body of the email you need to [run the report using the `ReportExecutionService.Render` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.render%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). First run the summary report rendered as HTML and make that the message body of the email.

```
message.Body = SummaryReport; // SummaryReport being the HTML report rendered above
```

Next, use the `ReportExecutionService.Render` method to render the detail report as Excel and add this as an attachment to your email:

```
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);                          // ms is the MemoryStream that the report rendered to
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(ms, filename)); // filename is the name you want the attachment to have in the email
```

Then send and you're done!

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtpserver.mycompany.com");
smtp.Send(message);
```

The bit I haven't tried is using the HTML output of the summary report as the body of the email but it should work. What I do is run the Sql to return the summary and simply manually format that as HTML to create the email body.